# Error packaging an Unreal Engine code plugin: Remote compiling requires a server name?

Tags: c++, plugins, unreal-engine4

I am trying to package a code plugin for Unreal Engine but, it keeps failing to build with the error:

`ERROR: Remote compiling requires a server name. Use the editor (Project Settings > IOS) to set up your remote compilation settings.`

However, I am not trying to package to IOS. (At least I am not meaning to lol). It seems I need to add a White-list or something to the `.uplugin` file? Everything online seemed pretty vague on how to do that exactly or what it really means.

I was wondering if someone here had any experience dealing with this or knew how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add whitelists or blacklist to each module in your UPLUGIN file, such as in this example:

```
{
    "FileVersion" : 3,
    .
    . (omitted for brevity)
    .
    "Modules" :
    [
        {
            "Name" : "YourModule",
            "Type" : "Runtime",
            "LoadingPhase" : "Default",
            "WhitelistPlatforms" :
            [
                "Win64",
                "Android"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "YourEditorModule",
            "Type" : "Editor",
            "LoadingPhase" : "PreDefault",
            "WhitelistPlatforms" :
            [
                "Win64"
            ]
        }
    ]   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the WhitelistPlatforms field in the wrong section. This fixed it